# cakephp edit posts doesnt do what it should do

Tags: cakephp-2.0

i want to edit my posts, but when i acess it http://... /posts/edit/2 it just shows Flash message that post has been updated, whats wrong ? It doesnt show the edit form...

```
function edit($id = NULL) {
    $this->Post->id = $id;
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->request->data = $this->Post->read(); 
    }else {
        if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('The post has been updated');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

My Edit page

```
<h2>Edit post</h2>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('post',array('action'=>'edit'));
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('body');
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type'=>'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->end('Edit Post');
?>
```

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#editing-posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if() condition is wrong :

1. If you post your data, then you only read your data and put it in $this->request->data for the edit form
2. Else : you save an empty $this->request->data and then redirect with a flash message.

So when you access the form, you do not post any data, thus save, then redirect. The fix is to modify the condition in the if() to read when you do not post and save when you post :

```
if(!$this->request->is('post'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You edit function shoud be as follow.

```
function edit($id = NULL) {
    $this->Post->id = $id;
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('The post has been updated');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
    }else{
       $this->request->data = $this->Post->read();
    }
}
```